# jQuery XML REST Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, rest, cross-domain, jsonp

I am calling [Version One REST API](http://community.versionone.com/sdk/Documentation/CoreAPI.aspx) and keep getting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www10.v1host.com/... Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` javascript error. I am sending GET request and XML content is expected to be returned in response. This is my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "xml",
  url: "https://www10.v1host.com/...",
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
  alert("Load was performed.");
  }
});
```

I have changed `dataType: "jsonp`" and with this I get response in this format:

```
jsonp1294354293197(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Asset ...</Asset>)
```

But get another javascript error: "`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`"

Is there a way how to get cross domain XML rest data (something like XMLp) or do a workaround for jsonp (prevent parsing JSON format and use my own - parse XML)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do a cross domain XMLHttpRequest, period.  As for your own parse XML - that would be only possible if you could get an escaped string instead of bare XML from server.  There is no magical parse JSON - JSONP technique just requests another script dynamically adding `<script src=...>` to header, everything inside is treated as normal JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. As I understand it calling cross-domain REST sending XML. The only way to communicate cross-domain is JSONP, right?

Comment: Yes, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP - this is a good explanation why this JSONP works and other things don't.

Comment: This isn't strictly true, browsers that accept the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header will do cross domain requests.

Comment: Good point.  You have to control the host to which you'd like to make a cross domain request though.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible as long as the server of the REST API (not your server) allows the request from a different origin by setting the [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) HTTP header, for example by setting the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" HTTP header in the response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

or

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
```

However what you can do is call your own server with Ajax, then use your own server as a kind of proxy to make a call to the other server in a different domain, parse the XML or HTML result with a suitable parser, and give the result back to the client:

```
 client --(Ajax)--> server
                    server --(HTTP)---> Site 
                    server <----------
 client <----------
```

Answer (score 0):

i know it's an old question but i think there is an better answer, via [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings):

> #### dataType
>
> multiple, space-separated values: As of jQuery 1.5, jQuery can convert
>   a dataType from what it received in the Content-Type header to what
>   you require. For example, if you want a text response to be treated as
>   XML, use "text xml" for the dataType. You can also make a JSONP
>   request, have it received as text, and interpreted by jQuery as XML:
>   "jsonp text xml." Similarly, a shorthand string such as "jsonp xml"
>   will first attempt to convert from jsonp to xml, and, failing that,
>   convert from jsonp to text, and then from text to xml.

Comment: This would be awesome but I still get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`