# call a vaadin application form php with jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, vaadin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access Control Allow Origin not allowed by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327218/access-control-allow-origin-not-allowed-by)
>   [Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

I used this code to call a vaadin application from PHP page:

```
$.get(
    "http://192.168.10.106:8080/FTTBManager/?restartApplication",
    { activate: "1", username: "Ahmed1.Hiwa@gold" }, 
    function(result) {
        alert ("Result Was : " +result);
        $('#divout').html(result); 
    }, 
    "text" 
)
```

but I get the following error:

> Origin localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Where is this code running from? `http://192.168.10.106`?

Comment: Your error is pretty descriptive

Comment: go to these stackoverflow links: - [access-control-allow-origin-not-allowed-by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327218/access-control-allow-origin-not-allowed-by) - [origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) - [jquery-xml-rest-access-control-allow-origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621056/jquery-xml-rest-access-control-allow-origin) - [xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-access-allow-for-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-o

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to access a URL from a server (192.168.10.106:8080) different from the one where the page is loaded from (localhost). This is called a cross-origin request and is blocked by most modern browsers. If you want to allow this request, the target server (192.168.10.106:8080) has to provide this information in its HTTP headers.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing for more details

Please be aware that Internet Explorer 8 seems to block any requests from localhost to non-localhost even if the target server has the CORS headers. Therefore you may want to test the same thing on a non-localhost server or in a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

same origin policy does not allow you to do an ajax request to another domain/port/protocol
and vaadin application is not supposed to work like that
You can try embed the vaadin application in your php page with iframe

[You can try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SPLHe/)

Comment: I had changed to localhost but I am still get same error

Comment: thank you for the answer. the vaadin application is a worker thread without a GUI or anything similar. how would the iframe solve the problem in this scenario ?

Comment: if it doesn't have any UI, why do you want to use Vaadin?    

and iframe still solve problem in this case, just don't let the iframe display (you can programmatically create an iframe on your event handler), the request will still be made.  

if it has to be ajax/xhr, you can send request to your vaadin application in one of your php pages, the ajax request will send request to that php page

Answer (score 0):

/FTTBManager/ url is php page add

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```