# cross domain request with dojo

Tags: ajax, dojo, cross-domain

I am attempting a cross domain request with dojo. External url is of MIME type text/html the only content on the page is something like 1236. I tried

```
dojo.require("dojo.io.script");
    dojo.ready(function() {
      dojo.io.script.get({
          url: "theexternalurl",
          callbackParamName: "jsoncallback",
          load: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          }
     });
});,
```

But that was no good. Any ideas on how this can be done with dojo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are bumping into the browser security here.  Cross-domain requests will only work when using iframes or injecting scripts (as you have done) and when the content of that script is valid *"text/javascript"*.

If you are trying to load *"text/html"* into the script, it won't work as it isn't a valid script.  It is something most of us have tried to do at some point.  I have spent hours trying to get around cross-domain restrictions and found the security blocking it to be solid.

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283905/retrieving-xml-data-from-a-rest-service-across-domains-with-dojo/13291431#13291431) here for more details.

If all you are trying to do is load the content onto the page then you could use an **<iframe>**.  However, if you are trying to parse the loaded content in some way than I'm afraid it is a dead-end.  Probably not the answer you were hoping for but it'll save you hours of frustration.