# parsing google alert feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-alerts

I try to parse a `Google Alert` feed via ajax but I get exception. This is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/01662123773360489091/16526224428036307178',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "xml"
    }).done(function(xml) {
        $.each($("item", xml), function(i, e) {
            $("#results").append($("enclosure").attr("url").text() + "<br />");
        });
    });
});
```

But I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/01662123773360489091/16526224428036307178. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Any help?

---

P.S: I already read several posts about parsing rss feeds via ajax and jquery, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Looks like a cross-domain issue. [This site](http://cypressnorth.com/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-xml-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/) has some notes on an approach.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you won't be allowed to use cross-domain scripting. See the answers here:

[jQuery XML REST Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621056/jquery-xml-rest-access-control-allow-origin)

> It is not possible as long as the server of the REST API (not your
>   server) allows the request from a different origin by setting the CORS
>   (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) HTTP header, for example by setting
>   the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" HTTP header in the response:
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

When looking at Google's headers, they don't provide that option:

```
$ curl -I 'http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/01662123773360489091/16526224428036307178'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 26 Jan 2014 23:46:50 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=3c2ff90717c79524:TM=1390780010:LM=1390780010:S=f9cyzI-rk2Nca7W3; expires=Tue, 26-Jan-2016 23:46:50 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: psfe
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Your only alternative is to use your server to fetch the values, then relay the values to your jQuery app.

Answer (score 3):

The server that you are talking to, `http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/...` isn't sending back a response header called `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.  Because it's not sending this header back allowing your site to contact it, your browser is blocking these requests.  This is a security measure that browsers implement.  No such restriction exists if you were doing this server side.  But client-side, it makes a difference and these restrictions are in place.

You will need to create a server side proxy (written in C#/Python/your choice) which in turn makes a request to your target URL.

In other words, your JQuery requests `http://example.com/proxy/alerts.py` which in turn calls that Google Alerts URL, and sends it to the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You plain copy-pasted the code from an **[answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575079/parsing-xml-using-jquery-and-ajax)**. 
Sure it will not work without at least trying to get the exact names out of that XML. `enclosure` is not in that feed results.

**One line of php and an AJAX call to that .php file:**

**getFeed.php**

```
<?php echo file_get_contents(htmlspecialchars($_GET['url'])); ?>
```

**yourpage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test Feeds by Roko C.B.</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="feeds"></p>

<script>
$(function(){

    var feedsHTML = ""

    $("<div/>").load('getFeed.php?url=http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/01662123773360489091/16526224428036307178', function(response, status, xhr){
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( response ),
            $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
            $entry = $xml.find( "entry" );
        $.each($entry, function(i){
            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var link =  $(this).find('link').attr("href");
            feedsHTML += "<a href='"+ link +"'>"+ title +"</a> <br>";
        });  
        $('#feeds').html(feedsHTML);
    });

});     
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

proof of concept? this the result I get:

```
<p id="feeds"><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.arabnews.com/news/516076&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNFhY_O6hwv7_d9EaA0pIyxFBstrlQ">Premarital drug <b>test</b> 'useless'</a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://secondgradesugarandspice.blogspot.com/2014/01/ready-to-write-test-prep-practice-for.html&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNH3y_Bf6rk_sPoshh6F5b45308daQ">Sugar and Spice: Ready to Write! <b>Test</b> Prep &amp; Practice For Lil <b>...</b></a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.csmonitor.com/Commentary/the-monitors-view/2014/0126/Ukraine-protests-a-test-for-the-idea-of-progress-as-inevitable&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNG9jCY57FsoCsrOZcP_timbk7odVg">Ukraine protests: a <b>test</b> for the idea of progress as inevitable</a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://tommorris.org/posts/8757&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNGdE5yyKMLFDlPA-qfq5C_aMn7O3g">The Minimal Viable Vegetarian <b>test</b> - Tom Morris</a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.navy-net.co.uk/joining-up-royal-navy-recruiting/73629-test.html&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNG4-3ZfVeGj1jA7FCBgQsD5jO9lwA"><b>Test</b> - Navy Net</a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.rawstory.com/rs/2014/01/26/dna-test-of-7000-year-old-tooth-overturns-popular-image-of-light-skinned-european-hunter-gatherers/&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNGjqu6y8GTcw1W_MFzen2nR0mBkIQ">DNA <b>test</b> of 7000-year-old tooth overturns popular image of light <b>...</b></a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://financialadvisercoach.com/2014/01/27/the-4-step-ethics-test-for-financial-professionals/&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNHn-o8toDuYi-PX4buRf0hZCfy4cw">The 4 Step Ethics <b>Test</b> for Financial Professionals – The Financial <b>...</b></a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://nypost.com/2014/01/26/test-tube-grown-meat-might-be-coming-to-brooklyn/&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNHd8-9mUEGl_VwJXkLDjInWQsGYTA"><b>Test</b> tube grown meat might be coming to Brooklyn</a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.ministryoftesting.com/2014/01/testing-presentations/&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNEfjw4Gr3Io70EVzZCx0lZjq7WOrg"><b>Testing</b> Presentations | Ministry of TestingMinistry of <b>Testing</b></a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://gospeldrivendisciples.blogspot.com/2014/01/the-test-of-fellowship-part-3.html&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNHX5Q5kZfeHSTo389RAVutxxwHWcg">*Gospel-driven Disciples: The <b>Test</b> of Fellowship (Part 3)</a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://forums.wpcentral.com/developers-beta-testing/260700-test-livezen-windows-phone.html&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNFjJuCwnVm_FGFbhrnQFuEG54bi2w"><b>Test</b> LiveZen on Windows Phone - Windows Phone Central Forums</a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.clevelandbanner.com/view/full_story/24452083/article-CSCC-to-offer-both-HiSet--GED-tests%3Finstance%3Dlatest_articles&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNEv00h7ou07AOehSP2l16Wmdv-h_Q">CSCC to offer both HiSet, GED <b>tests</b></a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.willitsnews.com/news/ci_24996241/api-school-test-scores-expected-vanish-california-2&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNFyKOmfO9R_E9VYbA6xkYnVmwIO6w">API school <b>test</b> scores expected to vanish in California for 2 years <b>...</b></a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.farmweekly.com.au/news/agriculture/cattle/dairy/preg-test-lifts-dairy-profit/2685288.aspx&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNFFCyCOwYkmo-BmaW44cEXclb8VqA">Preg <b>test</b> lifts dairy profit</a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://ajw.asahi.com/article/economy/technology/AJ201401270001&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNGXyAR1NLEgPti_Hfm8MJCETjvZtg">Researchers <b>test</b> sail for energy-efficient cargo ship</a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://bringatrailer.com/2014/01/25/one-of-one-1970-chrysler-electric-test-vehicle-1/&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNHgALMWfD8AHa87pDRzcGGtTFXf6A">One of One: 1970 Chrysler Electric <b>Test</b> Vehicle-1 - Bring a Trailer</a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://forums.linn.co.uk/bb/showthread.php%3Ftid%3D25860&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNGkR33R46DtOCfuwrqd5wBCC6BvDw">Interesting Hearing Study and <b>Test</b> - Linn Forums</a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.musiccitymiracles.com/2014/1/26/5347204/tennessee-titans-free-agents-sign-test-cut&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNEglk6qoddYkY_H6ISPAyRzteCJ5w">Tennessee Titans free agents: Sign, <b>test</b>, cut - Music City Miracles</a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://techlorebyigor.blogspot.com/2014/01/passing-my-piss-test.html&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNGFXpQSZbXZL2oKANeYbWA1q2_eng">tech lore by igor: Passing My Piss-<b>Test</b></a> <br><a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.lenorahenson.com/2014/01/test.html&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=&amp;cad=CAI&amp;usg=AFQjCNEqPuP8KuzAngKU5jO43pKtK1dahA">The Lenora Aura: <b>test</b></a> <br></p>
```